# How to write spans from different sevices in one trace?

Tags: python, opentracing, jaeger

Currently I have several services which are located in different docker containers and the main idea is that they are communicating by sending the json package between themselves. I want to see all the logs of the whole project inference in one trace.

I have tried the [tutorial](https://opentracing.io/guides/python/inject-extract/), however there is now one service in `jaeger UI`, which contains multiple traces of all the services. How can I write all the logs in one trace?

Currently it is looking like this:
[image]

and I want Encoder and NLU to be inside one trace.

Comment: Can you give sample code that you expect to work and is not? `inject`/`extract` should work the way you're describing.